# How do I manipulate filenames in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I have a bunch of images that I need to rename, so I can use them and I was wondering how to do this.

The way they need to be is that first 5 will be kept and then for the 6th I would write a number from 1-3. I only know that the first 5 are static; on pics belonging to same "family" and can be used for comparison and the 6th char is not known.

Example:

> 12345random.jpg
>
> 12345randomer.jpg
>
> 0987654more_random.jpg
>
> 09876awesome.jpg
>
> 09876awesomer.jpg
>
> 09876awesomest.jpg
>
> 09876soawesomegalaxiesexplode.jpg

would become.

> 12345.jpg
>
> 123452.jpg
>
> 09876.jpg
>
> 098761.jpg
>
> 098762.jpg

It would be cool if it would only handle the loop so that 3 pics could be only renamed and rest skipped.

I found some stuff on removing letters to certain point, but nothing that use, since I am quite poor at bash scripting.

Here is my approach, but it kind of sucks, since I tried modifying scripts I found, but the idea is there

```
//I could not figure how to remove the chars after 5th not the other way around
for file in .....*; do echo mv $file `echo $file | cut -c6-`; done
   
done
//problem also is that once the names conflict it produces only 1 file named 12345.jpg 2nd one will not be created
    //do not know how to read file names to array
    name=somefile
    if [[ -e $name.jpg]] ; then
        i=0
        while [[ -e $name-$i.jpg]] ; do
            let i++
        done
        name=$name-$i
    fi
    touch $name.jpg
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written

Comment: is python ok? It is present by default, and bash is kind of awkward for this

Comment: Sorry, I can hardly undestand bash. I'd like to learn how to do this kind of stuff in bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have:

```
new_file=${file%%[^0-9]*.jpg}.jpg
```

As a concept you can have this to rename files:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
    [[ $file == [0-9]*[^0-9]*.jpg ]] || continue  ## Just a simple check.
    new_file=${file%%[^0-9]*.jpg}.jpg
    [[ -e $new_file ]] || continue  ## Do not overwrite. Delete line if not wanted.
    echo "Renaming $file to $new_file."  ## Optional message.
    mv -- "$file" "$new_file" || echo "Failed to rename $file to $new_file."
done
```

If you're going to process files that also contain directory names, you'll need some more changes:

```
for file in /path/to/other/dirs/*.jpg *.jpg; do
    base=${file##*/}
    [[ $base == [0-9]*[^0-9]*.jpg ]] || continue
    if [[ $file == */* ]]; then
        new_file=${file%/*}/${base%%[^0-9]*.jpg}.jpg
    else
        new_file=${file%%[^0-9]*.jpg}.jpg
    fi
    [[ -e $new_file ]] || continue
    echo "Renaming $file to $new_file."
    mv -- "$file" "$new_file"
done
```

Comment: oh, thats like pregmatch, great. Now I just need to know how to step trough all files or read them to some kind of array equivalent.

Comment: @user1054844 There's no regex anywhere there. They are forms of [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). See also [paramater expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Thanks with this and some googling I should be fine. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

you can also try the following code 
but be careful all the files should be in .jpg format and pass the name of folder as an argument

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`ls $1`
for b in $a
do
echo $b
if (( i<4 ))
then 
c=`echo $b | cut -c1-5`
let i=i+1
c="$c$i.jpg"
echo $c
else
c=`echo $b | cut -c1-5` 
c="$c.jpg"
break
fi
mv $1$b $1$c
done
```

Comment: i did not add any check for .jpg file. you can edit a little bit